# PyGame Random Movement utilizing Pygame.math.vector2d() Crashing

Tags: python, pygame

Hey I need some help debugging why my code is crashing. I am fairly new to Python and Pygame and simply wanted to learn in my free time. I watched some physics tutorials in Pygame online and tried to create a simple game window where circles move randomly with no collisions. Here is my code where I believe the issue is:

```
for n in range(number_of_circles):
   size = random.randint(10,20)
   x = random.randint(size, screen_width - size)
   y = random.randint(size,screen_height - size)
   color = random.choice(colors)
   velocity = get_random_velocity()
   **my_circle = Ball(pygame.math.Vector2(x,y),size,color,velocity,0)
   my_circles.append(my_circle)**

direction_tick = 0.0

print('failed')
```

And here is the class :

```
class Ball:
    #the parameters that are already defined are optional.
    #width used to define the fill of the ball.
    #python cannot overload constructors. can only use one
    def __init__(self,position,size,color = (255,255,255),velocity =      pygame.math.Vector2(0,0),width = 1):
    self.position = position
    self.size = size
    self.color = color
    self.velocity = velocity
    self.width = width

    def display(self):
        rx,ry = int(self.position.x),int(self.position.y)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,self.color,(rx,ry),self.size,self.width)

    def move(self):
        self.position += self.velocity * dtime

    def change_velocity(self,velocity):
        self.velocity = velocity

def get_random_velocity():
    new_angle = random.uniform(0,math.pi*2)
    new_x = math.sin(new_angle)
    new_y = math.cos(new_angle)
    new_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(new_x,new_y)
    new_vector.normalize()
    new_vector *= initial_velocity #pixel movement per second
    return new_vector
```

Any help would be appreciated! Otherwise I will simply follow a different process to create random movement. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, describe the problem and the desired behaviour of the program in detail. And add the full traceback.

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. I scrapped that code altogether and started over again. What I have works a lot better, I created my own vectors. Thanks.

Comment: It would still be interesting to figure out what went wrong in the original program. The question is rather useless at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The application crashes when the length of the vector is 0. The [`normalize()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) method computes a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector). Therefore, the components of the vector are divided by the [Euclidean length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) of the vector. If the length of the vector is 0, this causes division by 0.
Even more, you are using the operation incorrectly. `normalize` does not change the vector itself, but returns a new vector with the same direction but length 1. In compare [`normalize_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize_ip) normalizes the vector in place so that its length is 1.

Use `normalize_ip` and test that at least 1 of the vector components is not 0:

```py
class Ball:
    # [...]

    def get_random_velocity():
        # [...]

       if new_vector.x != 0 or new_vector.y != 0:
           new_vector.normalize_ip()
```